# Where are My 421 Memory Leaks Coming from?

Tags: ios, memory-leaks

I am using Apple's Instruments tool to check out the current progress of my application and manage any leaks early. I seem to have **a lot** of leaks, but I cannot figure out where they are coming from.

In my application, I have a `SignInOperation` which is a subclass of `Operation`. It also conforms to `URLSessionDataDelegate` so that it can handle my requests without needing to use completion handlers. For example, when adding an instance of `SignInOperation` to an `OperationQueue` instance, the operation that performs updates to the UI can just check the `error` and `user` properties on the `SignInOperation` and handle UI updates accordingly since it will have the `SignInOperation` instance as a dependency.

The class follows:

```swift
import UIKit

/// Manages a sign-in operation.
internal final class SignInOperation: Operation, URLSessionDataDelegate {

    // MARK: - Properties

    /// An internal flag that indicates whether the operation is currently executing.
    private var _executing = false

    /// An internal flag that indicates wheterh the operation is finished.
    private var _finished = false

    /// The received data from the operation.
    private var receivedData = Data()

    /// The data task used for sign-in.
    private var sessionTask: URLSessionDataTask?

    /// The URL session that is used for coordinating tasks used for sign-in.
    private var localURLSession: URLSession { return URLSession(configuration: localConfiguration, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil) }

    /// The configuration used for configuring the URL session used for sign-in.
    private var localConfiguration: URLSessionConfiguration { return .ephemeral }

    /// The credentials used for user-sign-in.
    private var credentials: UserCredentials

    /// The current user.
    internal var currentUser: User?

    /// The error encountered while attempting sign-in.
    internal var error: NetworkRequestError?

    /// The cookie storage used for persisting an authentication cookie.
    internal var cookieStorage: HTTPCookieStorage?

    /// A Boolean value indicating whether the operation is currently executing.
    override internal(set) var isExecuting: Bool {
        get { return _executing }
        set {
            willChangeValue(forKey: "isExecuting")
            _executing = newValue
            didChangeValue(forKey: "isExecuting")
        }
    }

    /// A Boolean value indicating whether the operation has finished executing its task.
    override internal(set) var isFinished: Bool {
        get { return _finished }
        set {
            willChangeValue(forKey: "isFinished")
            _finished = newValue
            didChangeValue(forKey: "isFinished")
        }
    }

    /// A Boolean value indicating whether the operation executes its task asynchronously.
    override var isAsynchronous: Bool { return true }

    // MARK: - Initialization

    /// Returns an instane of `SignInOperation`.
    /// - parameter credentials: The credentials for user-sign-in.
    init(credentials: UserCredentials, cookieStorage: HTTPCookieStorage = CookieStorage.defaultStorage) {
        self.credentials = credentials
        self.cookieStorage = cookieStorage
        super.init()
        localURLSession.configuration.httpCookieAcceptPolicy = .never
    }

    // MARK: - Operation Lifecycle

    override func start() {
        if isCancelled {
            isFinished = true
            return
        }
        isExecuting = true
        let request = NetworkingRouter.signIn(credentials: credentials).urlRequest
        sessionTask = localURLSession.dataTask(with: request)
        guard let task = sessionTask else { fatalError("Failed to get task") }
        task.resume()
    }

    // MARK: - URL Session Delegate

    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, dataTask: URLSessionDataTask, didReceive response: URLResponse, completionHandler: @escaping (URLSession.ResponseDisposition) -> Void) {
        if isCancelled {
            isFinished = true
            sessionTask?.cancel()
            return
        }
        guard let statusCode = (response as? HTTPURLResponse)?.statusCode else { fatalError("Could not determine status code") }
        setError(from: statusCode)
        completionHandler(disposition(from: statusCode))
    }

    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, dataTask: URLSessionDataTask, didReceive data: Data) {
        if isCancelled {
            guard let task = sessionTask else { fatalError("Failed to get task") }
            task.cancel()
            return
        }
        receivedData.append(data)
    }

    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, didCompleteWithError error: Error?) {
        defer { isFinished = true }
        if isCancelled {
            guard let task = sessionTask else { fatalError("Failed to get task") }
            task.cancel()
        }
        if let statusCode = (task.response as? HTTPURLResponse)?.statusCode { setError(from: statusCode) } else if let taskError = error as? NSError { setError(from: taskError) }
        if self.error == nil {
            guard let taskResponse = task.response else { fatalError("Invalid response") }
            setAuthenticationCookie(from: taskResponse)
            processData()
        }
    }

    // MARK: - Helpers

    /// Handles the processing of the data received from the data task.
    private func processData() {
        currentUser = UserModelCreator.user(from: receivedData)
    }

    /// Handles the persistence of the returned cookie from the request's response.
    private func setAuthenticationCookie(from response: URLResponse) {
        guard let storage = cookieStorage else { fatalError() }
        let cookiePersistenceManager = ResponseCookiePersistenceManger(storage: storage)
        cookiePersistenceManager.removePreviousCookies()
        guard let httpURLResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse else { fatalError("Invalid response type") }
        if let cookie = ResponseCookieParser.cookie(from: httpURLResponse) {cookiePersistenceManager.persistCookie(cookie: cookie) }
    }

    /// Handles the return of a specified HTTP status code.
    /// - parameter statusCode: The status code.
    private func setError(from statusCode: Int) {
        switch statusCode {
        case 200: error = nil
        case 401: error = .invalidCredentials
        default: error = .generic
        }
    }

    /// Returns a `URLResponse.ResponseDisposition` for the specified HTTP status code.
    /// - parameter code: The status code.
    /// - Returns: A disposition.
    private func disposition(from code: Int) -> URLSession.ResponseDisposition {
        switch code {
        case 200: return .allow
        default: return .cancel
        }
    }

    /// Handles the return of an error from a network request.
    /// - parameter error: The error.
    private func setError(from error: NSError) {
        switch error.code {
        case Int(CFNetworkErrors.cfurlErrorTimedOut.rawValue): self.error = .requestTimedOut
        case Int(CFNetworkErrors.cfurlErrorNotConnectedToInternet.rawValue): self.error = .noInternetConnection
        default: self.error = .generic
        }
    }

}
```

Then, to see if everything works, I call the operation in `viewDidAppear:`, which results in all of the expected data being printed:

```swift
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        let credentials = UserCredentials(emailAddress: "xxxxxxx@xxxx.xx", password: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")
        let signInOp = SignInOperation(credentials: credentials)

        let printOperation = Operation()
        printOperation.addDependency(signInOp)
        printOperation.completionBlock = {
            if let error = signInOp.error { return print("\n====> Sign-in Error: \(error.message)\n") }
            if let user = signInOp.currentUser { print("\n====> User: \(user)\n") }
    }

        let queue = OperationQueue()
        queue.addOperations([signInOp, printOperation], waitUntilFinished: false)
    }

}
```

However, when using the Leaks profiler in Instruments, I get some alarming data.

[image: Screenshot of Leaks profiler run]

I don't really know where to start here. When I click on any of the detected leaks, I am not taken to my code that the leak originates from. I have watched a few tutorials and read Apple's documentation, but I am stuck trying to figure out where the leaks are coming from. It seems like a ridiculous amount/

I don't see anywhere in my code where I have strong reference cycles, so I am asking for some help with trying to figure out how to resolve the 421 detected leaks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that I *do* have two strong reference cycles, which are the two following properties in my `SignInOperation` subclass: `sessionTask` & `localURLSession`.

After making these properties `weak`, I no longer have leaks detected:

```swift
/// The URL session that is used for coordinating tasks used for sign-in.
private weak var localURLSession: URLSession { return URLSession(configuration: localConfiguration, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil) }

/// The configuration used for configuring the URL session used for sign-in.
private weak var localConfiguration: URLSessionConfiguration { return .ephemeral }
```

[image: Screenshot of Leaks profiler run]

Comment: Thanks for coming back and providing an answer. Can you post the code that you had to fix so that others can learn from it? (And be sure to come back and accept your answer as soon as SO lets you.)

Comment: @DuncanC Absolutely! I edited my answer to provide code changes.